# Magnetic levitation train vs ordinary train: which migh fare better in Martian environment?

Tags: environment, transportation, trains

I'm refining [my previous question about magnetic levitation trains on Mars](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/245832/magnetic-levitation-trains-on-mars). In my story, set on Mars, two settlements are connected by a railway line. Currently, it is an ordinary train of the type most common today on Earth. But I'm now considering whether a maglev train might be better. So the question is:

**Which of these types of trains would fare better in the Martian environment?**

Specifically, would Martian sand and dust cause significant issues to the maglev trains, which the ordinary trains would not experience or could easily mitigate? For example, only severe storms would create sand blockages on the track, and those could be easily cleared away, thus causing some delays at worst.

Would maglev trains require a tunnel to keep the sand and dust away from the track, thus making building the line even more expensive?

Or would raising the track off the ground be enough?

Comment: You know what, not enough data. Sandstorms on Mars aren't too strong compared to Earth's, and atmospheric pressure on Mars is significantly lower, so *maybe* raising the track would do for either type of train to provide protection from sandstorms. But again, maybe not, some sci-fi writers declared Martian dust to be too adhesive with grease to block spinning parts when they are not moving, causing problems. So only experiments would tell. So far I consider an ordinary train to fare better on Mars due to less overall precision requirements for them to operate.

Comment: @Vesper OK. But the ordinary train has a lot of rolling parts that require lubricant and thus would need a frequent cleaning.

Comment: I'm a huge stickler for conventional HSR where maglev isn't necessary. In your case, I think the maglevs are prima facie going to fare better (assuming dust does not cause excessive friction against the trains), but also that the cost in creating such a system is probably less than just putting a plastic tube around conventional tracks (there's no O2 in the environment anyways)

Answer (score 3):

Martian dust is likely to be an engineering nightmare, as it is very fine indeed and quite chemically reactive. It is going to get in *everything*. It won't have quite the same problems as, say, lunar dust (wind action will smooth the grains and reduce the size of large grains over time) but it is going to cause problems with all seals and joints and basically anywhere you get two surfaces that are sporadically separated or move against each other, and are exposed to the Martian atmosphere (even occasionally).

> would raising the track off the ground be enough?

The actual thickness of deposited dust is [often remarkably low](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/41471/30460), because the atmosphere is so thin and the windspeeds low, there's not much opportunity to produce thick layers or drifts of dust. The dust is statically charged though and sticks to things. This means that anything outdoors during a big dust storm is going to get a very fine layer of particles stuck to it, regardless of whether it is at ground level or raised a decent distance above it. Smaller local events, like dust devils, might move and deposit larger masses of dust which would be more problematic, and raised tracks would probably be less subject to thicker deposits or drifts. This would benefit both kinds of train, though wheeled trains may suffer more from debris on the track.

Maglev trains don't need wheel bearings or indeed contact with the "track" when the train is, uh, in flight, which is a massive point in their favor. At least some of the dust [magnetic](https://physicsworld.com/a/rover-reveals-magnetic-mars/) which is probably undesirable, but it is a lot easier to clean smooth surfaces than it is to remove and filter contaminated lubricants.

> Would maglev trains require a tunnel to keep the sand and dust away from the track, thus making building the line even more expensive?

I suspect the conventional trains would be the ones more in need of environmental protection under normal circumstances, and it might not be possible to operate them at all during a storm (that could last weeks or even months) if they lacked a protective tunnel.

That said, both kinds of train could benefit from enclosures, not just to keep the dust out but also for general safety (things running at potentially aircraft speeds at ground level have significant risks, both to themselves and to others) but also for radiation shielding, which is an important consideration under such a thin atmosphere.

Comment: In the case of a maglev, could the high speed of the train fan the dust away from the track, especially if it is elevated?

Comment: @KrišjānisLiepiņš the air is very thin, so it is difficult for even a fairly high speed train to generate much of a wake or "bow wave". It might be enough to remove dust that is _under_ the train, but at that point it risks getting caught in the magnetic fields of the maglev motors anyway. I feel like having a purpose-built low-speed sweeper train might be a more reliable and safer way to do the job.